# SwiftUI Button Not Clickable With Overlay

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I have a Button with an overlay, but it is not clickable. If I take the overlay off, it becomes clickable. How can I make it work with the overlay?

```
Button {
                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                UIPasteboard.general.string = viewModel.promoCode?.code ?? ""
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(viewModel.promoCode?.code ?? "")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.uStadium.primary))
                        .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 14)))
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                    Spacer()
                    Image("copyIcon")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.uStadium.primary))
                        .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }

            }
            .overlay (
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke(Color(UIColor.uStadium.primary), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [10]))
                    .frame(height: 42)
                    .background(Color(UIColor.uStadium.primary.withAlphaComponent(0.2)))
            )
            .frame(height: 42)
            .cornerRadius(8)
```

Comment: What happens if you put the overlay on the HStack instead of the Button?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is adding `.allowsHitTesting(false)` modifier at the view inside of the `overlay`.

The reason why touch is not working is overlay modifier layers a secondary view in front of current view. So when user tap the button they were actually tapping the overlayed view.

The `allowsHitTesting(false)` stop a view from receiving any kind of taps, and any taps automatically continue through the view on to whatever is behind it.

**Simple example:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("dd")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "house").resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        }
        .overlay (
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).allowsHitTesting(false)
        )
    }
}
```

and touch works!